# Why is Authorize.Net DPM relay-response without data in sandbox mode?

Tags: php, laravel, authorize.net

I am correctly getting the checkout process to be approved by Authorize.Net and the relay-response is correctly hitting my response URL.  But there is no POST data being detected.  A var_dump reveals array(0) {}.

```
<?php
    require_once '../anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php';
    $host = HOST;
    $url = $host . '/order/response/';
    $api_login_id = API_LOGIN_ID;
    $transaction_key = TRANSACTION_KEY;
    $md5_setting = MD5;
    $amount = $order->total;
    $orderId = $order->id;
    echo AuthorizeNetDPM::getCreditCardForm($amount, $orderId, $url, $api_login_id, $transaction_key);
?>
```

The service successfully hits the following code.

```
<?php
    public function response() {
        $response = Input::all();
        // var_dump($response); return;
        if (isset($response["x_invoice_num"])) {
            $orderId = $response["x_invoice_num"];
            $order = Order::find($orderId);
            try {
                $order->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->log("\nERROR: \n" . $e->getMessage());
                return View::make('home.error')->with('message', $e->getMessage());
            }
            $order->orderstatus_id = 1;
        }
        return View::make('home.processing')->with('response', $response);
    }
?>
```

$response is an empty array.

Comment: Anyone? Any reason that the service is returning no data?

Comment: Oh and I am using the new DPM transaction.